# Removing an element from the vector without removing the elements after

Tags: c++, vector

Coming from Java and using the ArrayList class has me all frustrated when trying to learn the C++ equivalent (Vectors).

I'm writing a function that removes a certain int given from a vector of ints. For awhile I could not figure out why it was causing a segmentation fault. After looking at the documentation I realized .erase also removes any element after the one being erased. Which is definitely not what I want to do, so I'm a little lost of how I would go about removing only a single element from a vector without removing the elements after.

Function that I currently have which causes a segmentation fault:

```
void remove(int n){

    for(int a=0; a<list.size(); a++){

        if(list.at(a)==n){
            list.erase (list.begin()+(n-1));
            cout << n << " has been erased" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming from your example that you are only expecting a single occurrence of 'n' then you might want to consider using std::set instead of a vector. In which case you'll only need a single statement to remove the element from the set - 'set.erase( n );'. Of course if you have multiple occurrences then you'll need a list or vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `n` as an element, but are also using it as an index. I don't think this is what you want.

If you replace `(n-1)` by `a`, it should work:

```
        list.erase(list.begin()+a);
```

Alternative way to remove a single element, using [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) and [`erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
void removeOne(int n){
    vector<int>::iterator found = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), n) ;
    if (found!=list.end())
        list.erase(found);
}
```

Comment: You are right! Needed to use a instead of n! Silly mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> v; 
// fill it up somehow
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 99), v.end()); 
// really remove all elements with value 99
```

Comment: This will remove all of the elements with the given value, not just the first.  A C++ idiomatic solution to removing just the first would be to use `std::find` to get an iterator to the element to be erased, and then erase it (having first verified that there was such an element---`v.erase( v.end() )` is undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You'll be needing `iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last );`

see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/). (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

Comment: I completely misinterpreted your needs, ignore me! ^_^